# Howto Highlight Code Background Color by line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a eclipse plugin and trying to highlight parts of the Code with a backround color. Is there any option to highlight to change the backround color in the editor by line numbers.

For Example:

editor.highlightLines(2,5,"red"); I  i

There are so much informations when i googled for it. Annotations, Makers etc. but noone could give me a Tutorial or a link to and API which can do what i need. I only got informations for syntax highlighting, but i want to highlights parts of the code by line number.

Comment: Is this a new editor that you are writing or are you trying to add to an existing editor?

Comment: I have a ViewPart with ErrorMessages and if you click on the ErrorMessage the File java-class which belongs to this error will open in Eclipse this part works and now i want to highlight in this opend windows the lines of the error with another backround color and it would be nice if the cursor jumps to this position

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as long as the editor implements `ITextEditor`:

```java
IEditorPart editorPart = page.openEditor(new FileEditorInput(file), getEditorId() , true);

ITextEditor textEditor;
if (editorPart instanceof ITextEditor) {
  textEditor = (ITextEditor)editorPart;
} else {
  textEditor = (ITextEditor)editorPart.getAdapter(ITextEditor.class);
}

IEditorInput input = editorPart.getEditorInput();

IDocumentProvider provider = textEditor.getDocumentProvider();

provider.connect(input);

IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);

IRegion region = document.getLineInformation(lineNumber - 1);

int fileOffset = region.getOffset();
int fileLength = region.getLength();

provider.disconnect(input);

textEditor.selectAndReveal(fileOffset, fileLength);
```

(extracted from `org.eclipse.debug.ui.console.FileLink` which the console code uses). I have left out many error checks of exception catches.

Comment: Ok so you get the instance of the editor but where do you add the annotaions?

Comment: This just uses the editor's selected text color, any more depends a lot on exactly which editor.